# Cocos2d-Swift : CCProgressNodeTypeBar not found in Swift

Tags: swift, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-swift

Here is ObjectiveC Code:

```
CCSprite *progress = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"progress.png"];
mProgressBar = [CCProgressNode progressWithSprite:progress];
mProgressBar.type = CCProgressNodeTypeBar;
```

I Tried to Convert it to Swift:

```
    var progress = CCSprite.spriteWithImageNamed("progress.png") as! CCSprite
    mProgressBar = CCProgressNode.progressWithSprite(progress) as  CCProgressNode
    mProgressBar.type = CCProgressNodeTypeBar
```

In Obj.C version no error, for Swift it is giving error for CCProgressNodeTypeBar. API not found. How to solve? Any alternatives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative Solution, we can use CCProgressNodeType.Bar :

```
mProgressBar.type = CCProgressNodeType.Bar
```